# Is Realm data left unencrypted if Android application crashes?

Tags: android, realm

I have configured my Realm instance to use encryption. I get an instance of Realm in my activity onCreate and close it in onDestroy. If the activity crashes and onDestroy is not called, will my Realm data be left in an unencrypted state?

Comment: That seems highly unlikely, but I'm actually not sure how the encryption part works because it seems to be in the native core. Don't forget that encrypted Realms cannot be compacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I found for your question is here: https://realm.io/news/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/

> The way encryption is built is very similar to how it is typically
>   done in Linux. Since we memory map the whole file, we can protect
>   parts of that memory. If anyone tries to read from this encrypted
>   chunk, we can throw a file system violation that we can then catch and
>   say, “Oh, someone’s trying to access this bit of encrypted data.
>   Decrypt only that chunk and pass it back to the user.” We can do this
>   in a very efficient way while having very secure technology.

So, the answer to the question is no: The data is decrypted in-memory as is being used, "on demand", not before.

Comment: So your impression is that the decrypted data is in virtual memory that gets lost when the application crashes?

Comment: That is correct. Any decrypted data is just in memory, which will be lost if the application crashes. The data on disk is always encrypted.